# Is there a smart pattern for nullable settings using data binding?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, design-patterns

In my application I have controls that are bound to object properties.

But the controls always look like this:

- A check box
- Label that explains the setting
- The edit control (eg: text box)

When the check box is unchecked, I use binding to disable the text box.

When the check box is unchecked, I want the property value to be null.

When the check box **is** checked, I would like the property to contain the value from the text box.

The text box could be be a `NumericUpDown`, `ComboBox`, `DatePicker`, and so on.

Is there a smart way to get this behavior using binding, or is code my only option?

I really would like to a build a control that supports that and re-use it.

Comment: The answer depends on the UI toolkit you're using - Windows Forms? WPF? ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you'd want to bind to a custom object, which had a 'UseNull' property on it, as well as the underlying property.

The 'real' control for non-null values could be then picked using a TemplateSelector.

At least that's how I'd initially attack that problem.